# Issues with the new Sitecore Support portal

Tags: support

**Sitecore has released a new version of the Sitecore Support & Self-Service Portal at https://support.sitecore.com**

You might have issues like the following and you need to find the answer:

- I was able to log in to the old portal before but cannot log in to the new portal.
- I never used the support portal before and cannot log in to the new portal.
- I cannot find my old support case on the new portal.
- I cannot open new support cases because Account field does not show the name of the customer I am working with.
- My license.xml file does not get accepted in the Register customer license form when I upload it.
- I do not have access to the license.xml file but need a specific account to be added to the list of the companies I work with.
- I am an Implementation Partner and want to open a support case on behalf of the customer I am representing. Which account should I select in the Account field of the support case creation form?

But where can you find the answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former support portal at https://support.sitecore.net is no longer active.

The new version of the Sitecore Support & Self-Service Portalis designed to improve user experience, add new self-service capabilities, and functions as a single technical support channel for Sitecore Experience Platform, Experience Commerce, and Content Hub.

**Sitecore has released a Knowledge base article where you can find the answer for all of these questions: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/467193**

Also if you cannot solve the issue you can send an email to [NewSupportPortalFeedback@sitecore.com](http://mailto:NewSupportPortalFeedback@sitecore.com) for assistance.

For detailed information on how to use the new Sitecore Support & Self-Service Portal, please visit https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/263106